# Conditionally prompting for optional parameters

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Version: Crystal Report 2008

I have 2 parameters that prompt the user to enter in information.

Parameter 1 (Boolean):
Select All Time Periods?
- True: Show all time periods
- False: I will choose the date

Parameter 2 (date/time):
Dynamic date time based on date/time field.

If the first parameter is true, then I want to omit parameter 2.  If the first parameter is false, then I want to prompt the user for the date.  Any idea on how to this?

Also, I have the following in my 'Record Select'

```
(if {?Select All Time Periods}= True then
date({ReleaseDate.ReleaseDate}) >= date(currentdatetime)
else if {?Select All Time Periods}= False then
date({?Select Release Date}) = {ReleaseDate.ReleaseDate})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do away with the boolean parameter altogether. Keep your {?Select Release Date}, but set it to optional (available in CR 2008 and onwards). Then, put this in your record selection

```
if hasvalue({?Select Release Date} then 
    {ReleaseDate.ReleaseDate} = {?Select Release Date}
else {ReleaseDate.ReleaseDate} >= currentdate
```

By default, if a user does nothing with the parameters, only release dates *in the future* will be selected. If you truly want to select all release dates, past and future, you can simply omit the else-statement.

Comment: I did try that, but Business Objects would throw an error when trying to run the report.  I did get my initial process to work.

Comment: ERROR: A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here. Details: errorKind Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\{047CB282-281F-4E5E-8ABB-ABC695245AC2}.rpt: Error in formula . 'if hasvalue({?Release Date})=false then ' A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here. Details: errorKind

Comment: Hmm... you don't need the "=true" or "=false" when checking booleans in conditionals, but that shouldn't cause an error. But, if you are trying to use {?Release Date} in the case when it does not actually have a value, then that might give an error.

Comment: I get the following if I remove the "=True" or "=False":  ERROR: A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here. Details: errorKind Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\{B0872BF6-482D-446C-B174-E307BA51155F}.rpt: Error in formula . 'if hasvalue({?Release Date}) then ' A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here. Details: errorKind