# Parameter Field issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having a problem with one of my parameter fields. I have YES to show all the results with yes on, and NO for all of those with no on, on other parameter fields if i leave the field as "..." it will show both yes and no. I don't seem to be able to select "..." as a default value. When i click "..." in the parameter field no results are shown.

please see the below screenshots relevant to this column:

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Image 3

[image]

Image 4

[image]

If you require any more information, please ask.

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'...' isn't a value that can be set.  It is what is displayed when a value hasn't been chosen.

You can either:

- make it an optional parameter; see [Conditionally prompting for optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163188/conditionally-prompting-for-optional-parameters)
- make it a multi-select parameter and look for the presence of one or the other or both

In both cases, it would be easier for you if you used a Boolean parameter rather than a String.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I changed it to a multi-select parameter just for ease. I will have a look into the other options later.